# Git - info on tracking branch

Tags: git, git-log, git-branch

I would like to know which is the git command line giving informations about tracking branch ?

I have an integration branch which track the origin/integration (`git branch --track integration origin/integration`) but i want to be sure and check the connection between the local tracking branch and the remote tracking branch...

I know the `git remote show origin`. But if i'm not online...?

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 4):

You can do `git branch -a` to see that. Or just do `git config -e` to see the config, which the source of truth.

And also, `git remote show origin -n` uses cached information.